# How do I show that $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{x}{n^2}$ is not uniformly convergent on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

How do I show something is not uniformly convergent? I was thinking maybe showing that the property of uniform convergence(continuity/boundedness preserved, integrity commutes etc) doesn't hold, but the problem is I haven't learned how to calculate $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}1/n^2$

Comment: So your function is $f : x\in \mathbb{R} \mapsto \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{x}{n^2}$?

Comment: Simply apply the definition: it's uniformly convergent if given $\epsilon>0$ you can find a $N$ such that for all $x\in\Bbb R$, $|f(x)-x\pi^2/6|<\epsilon$. Is it possible? What happens given this $N$, if you take a larger $x$?

Comment: I wanted to see $f_n (x)=\sum^{n}_{k=0}\frac{x}{k^2}$ is uniformly convergent to some function and the domain is $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut This is a good hint but the kid does not know that the series of $1/n^2$ does converge to that value...

Comment: Is there a way to know the uniform convergence without knowing how to compute the given function? I think I learned in calculus 2, by integration I think... but I appreciate the answer! I will think about it.

Comment: @able20 Aaaah then it is not the same thing, you want to show that $(f_n)_n$ is not uniformly convergent?

Comment: $f_n$ is a partial sum, and I wanted to prove that partial sum, which is a function of $x$ and $n$, doesn't uniformly converge to some $f(x)$ on $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: In order to show that a sequence of function $(f_n)_n$ is uniformly convergent you need to show that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$, $f-f_n$ is bounded and if it the case then you need then to show that $(||f-f_n||_{\infty}^{\mathbb{R}})_n$ converges to $0$.

Comment: @Turing He doesn't have to. It's not difficult to prove the series without $x$ has a limit. Just call it $L$ and apply the definition.

Comment: @Jean-Claude Arbaut Can I say that for a given $N$, $f(N,x)-x\pi^2/6$ is a linear function of $x$ so it cannot be controlled(with big $x$, the absolute value of it will diverge)?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $f : x \in \mathbb{R} \mapsto \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \dfrac{x}{k^2}$ and for all $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$, $f_n: x \in \mathbb{R} \mapsto \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac{x}{k^2}$. We know that $(f_n)_n$ converges simply to $f$. But for $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$, we have $ f-f_n : x \in \mathbb{R} \mapsto \displaystyle \sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty} \dfrac{x} {k^2} = x \sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty} \dfrac{1} {k^2}$ that is not bounded because $\sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty} \dfrac{1} {k^2} \neq 0$ therefore $(f_n)_n$ doesn't uniformly converge on $\mathbb{R}$.